# Problema al conseguir elemento con xpath, selenium y python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, selenium

estoy tratando de conseguir un elemento de la siguiente pagina

**https://fcm.org.co/simit/#/home-public**

y el elemento en concreto es el siguiente:

```
<button type="submit" id="consultar" aria-label="Consultar estado de cuenta" data-step="3" class="btn btn-primary font-weight-bold btn-sm py-1" data-orig-font-size="14px" data-orig-line-height="21px" data-orig-letter-spacing="0"><em class="bx bx-search align-middle fs-27"></em></button>
```

y estoy usando este xpath:
buscar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@aria-label="Consultar estado de cuenta"]')

y me aparece esto en la terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\svalenciab\OneDrive - Turia\Desktop\aprendiendo web scrapping> [19768:2040:0106/164204.770:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(226)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
```

[19768:2040:0106/164204.770:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(229)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
[19768:2040:0106/164204.771:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(232)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.

Este es el codigo que tengo escrito hasta el momento:

```html
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://fcm.org.co/simit/#/home-public')

busqueda = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="txtBusqueda"]')
busqueda.send_keys('72333632')


buscar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="consultar"]')
buscar.click
```

Intento enviar al cuadro de texto un string y si lo recibe, no se que podra ser el problema.

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda

Comment: me tome el atrevimiento de copiar tal cual el código que tienes, y me funciona correctamente, solo agregué `()` a `buscar.click()`

Comment: Hola @Lucas Damian, muchas gracias eso soluciono mi problema, pero ahora tengo otro inconveniente, resulta que la pagina cuando le doy click con el script, enseguida me manda un capcha para resolverlo alguna manera para que no suceda esto???

Comment: échale un ojo a esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/a/58876531/11539076